# problem inserting datat from java into mysql

Tags: java, mysql

```
            String user=new String(tf1.getText());
            String pass=new String(pf1.getPassword());
            String mb=new String(tf2.getText());
            String email=new String(tf3.getText());
            String query="INSERT into user_info (username,password,email_id,mobile number) VALUES('"+user+"','"+pass+"','"+email+"','"+mb+"')";
            try {
                    Connection myConn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaproject","root","noor1032");
                    System.out.println("databse connected");
                    PreparedStatement myStat=myConn.prepareStatement(query); 
                    System.out.println("statement prepapred");
                    myStat.setString(1, user); 
                    myStat.setString(2, pass); 
                    myStat.setString(3, email); 
                    myStat.setString(4, mb); 
                    myStat.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("query executed");
                    myConn.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "saved");
               }    
            catch(Exception f)
                {
                    System.err.println("Got an exception!");
                    System.err.println(f.getMessage());
                }
```

The exception it is displaying is "Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)." please help!!!

Comment: On which line does the exception happen ?

Comment: it was not mentioned, probably it would have been at  "myStat.setString(1,user)"

Answer (score 3):

replace this:

`"INSERT into user_info (username,password,email_id,mobile number) VALUES('"+user+"','"+pass+"','"+email+"','"+mb+"')";`

by this:

`"INSERT into user_info (username,password,email_id,mobile_number) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";`

you are inserting the values in corresponding order later when you do

```
myStat.setString(1, user); 
myStat.setString(2, pass); 
myStat.setString(3, email); 
myStat.setString(4, mb);
```

Comment: i did it, now the "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'number) VALUES('ekfb','ekrjfb','erkgjbn','wrgjn')' at line 1" is the exception which is coming

Comment: updated!, the error was the column name `mobile number`. should it be `mobile_number`?

Comment: no, in sql table the column name is "mobile number" only

Comment: i used "mobile number" only, then this exception is occuring

Comment: not sure if it works but try using `mobile\u00A0number` instead of `mobile number`. btw why do you have a sql column with spaces on name?
in the other answer @forpas said a way to solve that using 'mobile number'

Comment: i changed mobile number to mobile_number... and it worked thankyou so much ....really nice of you

Comment: @JashandeepSingh you are welcome. Remember to vote the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a prepared statement, change to this:

```
String query="INSERT into user_info (username,password,email_id,`mobile number`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
```

The parameters will be inserted later with all the calls to `setString()` method.

**Edit** If the name of the column is `mobile number` then  in the select statement write
 **`mobile number`** or **[mobile number]**

Comment: i have written "mobile number" only

Comment: No this is not right, it will return the string "mobile number"